# Why is this comment character required for correct rendering?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

There is a comment between two child nodes down below, that if removed would cause tree to render completely wrong. Why?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black, thin, minimum height=3em]

\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    supervisor/.style={%
        text centered, text width=12em,
        text=black
    },
    teammate/.style={%
        text centered, text width=12em,
        text=black
    },
    subordinate/.style={%
        grow=down,
        xshift=-3.2em, % Horizontal position of the child node
        text centered, text width=12em,
        edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.205) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}
    },
    level1/.style ={level distance=4em,anchor=west},
    level2/.style ={level distance=8em,anchor=west},
    level3/.style ={level distance=12em,anchor=west},
    level4/.style ={level distance=16em,anchor=west},
    level 1/.style={%
        edge from parent fork down,
        sibling distance=14em,
        level distance=5em
    }
]
    \node[anchor=south,supervisor](super){Supervisor\\Supervisory position\\Location}[]

    child{node [teammate] {Teammate6\\Position4\\Location4}
        child[subordinate,level1] {node {Subordinate1}}
        child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate2}}}
    % - why is this comment required for proper rendering of the tree???
    child{node [teammate] {Teammate7\\Position5\\Location5}
        child[subordinate,level1] {node {First\\Subordinate}}
        child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate2}}
        child[subordinate,level3] {node {Third\\Teammate}}
        child[subordinate,level4] {node {Longtext-\\teammate}}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

With a comment:

[image]

Without a comment:

[image]

Comment: I'm actually quite surprised that it even works. You're in general not allowed to have empty lines inside `\node ... ;`, since empty line is transformed into `\par` and that can cause troubles.

Comment: You can make that an answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, in general, you are not allowed to have empty lines inside `\node ... ;` or `\coordinate ... ;` or `\draw ... ;` or such. The reason is that empty line isn't just a whitespace that is easily trimmed, it transforms into a `\par`, which can cause a mess in such places.

So It's actually a bit of a surprise that the code compiles with those empty lines. It's certainly better to avoid them: either remove them completely, or at least add `%`, which "eats everything until the next end-of-line including this end-of-line", so no `\par` is generated.